# How to open locally saved PDF file in an Android WebView?

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I have tried to open a locally saved PDF file in a WebView. I can open it by using IntentService, but I want to open it in a WebView. Except for PDFs, all other files are working for me.

I have used the codes below:

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(mFilePath));
webView.loadData(mFilePath, mimeType, "UTF-8");
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `WebView` has no built-in ability to display PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Docs Viewer to read your pdf online:
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);

Answer (score 0):

You can also use iframes.

```
pdfView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
WebSettings settings = pdfView.getSettings();
settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
pdfView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
pdfView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
settings.setAllowFileAccess(false);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
settings.setSaveFormData(false);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

String html = "<iframe src=\"http://docs.google.com/gview?url=" + 
    path + "&embedded=true&wmode=opaque\"" +
    "style=\"width:600px; height:900px;\" scrolling=\"no\"" + 
    "frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

pdfView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: Is $path a URI to a local pdf file/resource or does it point to a web pdf file/resource?