# Pdf file from my device does not load in WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

I am trying to load a PDF file via `WebView`. I tried almost all the answers here in StackOverflow but still failed. Here is my resulting code:

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.setContentDescription("application/pdf");
webView.loadUrl("file:///data/user/0/com.example.pdfwebviewer/files/masterlist.pdf");
```

I derived this code from a couple of sources:

1. [How to open local PDF file in WebView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613505/how-to-open-local-pdf-file-in-webview-in-android)
2. [Can't open a local PDF in webview using file://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861147/cant-open-a-local-pdf-in-webview-using-file)
3. [Open PDF in a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434487/open-pdf-in-a-webview/43087727#43087727)

What did I miss?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291980/implementing-pdf-js-in-android-to-read-from-sd-card/24938424

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have to try to use some library, because android-WebView doesn't seem to support `.pdf` files.

1. [Mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861147/cant-open-a-local-pdf-in-webview-using-file)
2. [Mentioned here in a comment to the main question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407403/how-to-open-locally-saved-pdf-file-in-an-android-webview)

**So what Library**

Alot of answers on this site like this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49226127/how-to-open-local-pdf-file-in-webview-android-studio) recommends this library to read local pdf files:

[AndroidPdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)

Answer (score -1):

This solution works for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9139859/5653463

looks like this:

```
val googleDocs = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
view.loadUrl("googleDocs${URLEncoder.encode(url.toString()"ISO-8859-1")}")
```